# NoMethodError: undefined method `color_enabled=' when run capybara test in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `color_enabled='  for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007ff1ba922ad0> 
from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-console-0.2.7/lib/rspec-console/config_cache.rb:69:in `method_missing'
```

I do not know how to solve it~

any suggestion? thx~

Comment: The is extremely broad and shows an extreme lack of effort.  Could you please elaborate on how the error is produced, and what you have looked at in trying to solve it!

Comment: what I already try: update pry. update all gem. google this error message, and find that rspec core Remove color_enabled as an alias of color. (Jon Rowe). (https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/Changelog.md). I set config.color_enabled = true, but it was no use. config.color = true was no use too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After set

gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14.2'
  gem 'rspec-console', '~> 0.2.7'

everything work fine, I think this issue is rspec and rspec-console version conflict problem. Maybe it is related to https://github.com/nviennot/rspec-console/pull/14 .

Comment: This is because the config option changed after rspec 3.1, change the config option in the answer above to get it working with 3.1 and over

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this same error when upgrading to rspec-core 3.1.7. I fixed this particular issue by changing

```
config.color_enabled = true
```

to

```
config.color = true
```

in spec_helper.rb. However, I encounter additional rspec errors and decided to revert to rspec-core 2.14.8 for now.