# Why does color_enabled work in Ruby's rspec 3.0.3 throw a NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-console

I have a ruby spec file called `mySpec`. In the spec file, there is a specific test at line #37 that I want to run. However, when I run that test, I get a `NoMethodError`:

```
$ rspec -v
3.0.3

$ bundle exec rspec myspec.rb:37
Coverage report generated for RSpec to coverage. 79 / 223 LOC (35.43%) covered.
spec_helper.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `color_enabled=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007f905e2ea2c0> (NoMethodError)
```

Here is what the relevant portion of the `spec_helper.rb` file looks like:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    # Use color in STDOUT
    config.color_enabled = true
    config.tty = true
    config.order = "random"
end
```

So why can't I find `color_enabled`? I tried adding `rspec-rails` and `rspec-console` to the my Gemfile as suggested [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351557/nomethoderror-undefined-method-color-enabled-when-run-capybara-test-in-rails). But that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's `color_enabled?`, but there isn't a `color_enabled=`.  Try this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color = true
  config.tty = true
  config.order = "random"
end
```